# WebAPI Deleting a Database entry using Dapper and DevExtreme

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, devexpress, asp.net-core-2.0

I've created a `WebAPI` using `Asp .Net Core 2` with a `DevExtreme` front rendering my database information to a datagrid. I've got the ability to add new rows to my database, but I'm having an issue deleting any rows via the front end.

This is what I have so far.

The dapper logic:

```
public void Remove(int id)
{
    var sql = @"DELETE FROM [dbo].[MyTable]   
                WHERE ID = @ID";

    using (var dbConnection = Connection)
    {
        dbConnection.Open(); 
        dbConnection.Execute(sql, new { ID = id });   
    }
}
```

I've tested the SQL code above directly in SSMS and it does work.

Next, my web API controller has the following `HttpDelete` method:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var record = _bukRepository.FindById(id);

    _bukRepository.Remove(record.ID);
    return Ok();
}
```

Finally, I am rendering my via `jQuery` and I've called my delete method like so:

```
$(function () {
    var url = "http://" + window.location.host;
    $("#grid").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: DevExpress.data.AspNet.createStore({
            key: "ID",
            loadUrl: url + "/api/WebAPI/",
            insertUrl: url + "/api/WebAPI/",
            updateUrl: url + "/api/WebAPI/",
            deleteUrl: url + "/api/WebAPI/"
        }),
        remoteOperations: true,
        columns: [
            {
                dataField: "ID",
                caption: "ID"
            }

        ],
        editing: {
            allowUpdating: true,
            allowDeleting: true,
            allowAdding: true
        }
    }); 
});
```

When I run my code and hit the delete button, my methods get hit but it gets returned as `Not found` as the ID isn't being passed from the UI to my delete method.

what it is that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you please share your network tab and specific this request and this `api/WebAPI' i assume WebAPI is not a controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your Delete action parameter `key` since this name is used on the client to pass the record key when deleting a record:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult Delete(int key)
{
    var record = _bukRepository.FindById(key);

    _bukRepository.Remove(record.ID);
    return Ok();
}
```